# Late static bindings

Tags: php, static, this

Do we need to use the `static::$attribute` instead of `$this->attribute` in the following condition :

**b.php**

```
class B {
public function tellAttribute(){
// $this OR static ??
    echo $this->attribute;
}
}
```

**a.php**

```
include 'b.php';

class A extends B {
public $attribute = 'foo';
}

$test = new A();
$test->tellAttribute();
```

Asking this because to me it shouldn't work unless I use `static::$attribute` but its still echoing **foo**. What is the reason?

Comment: Forget about the static, it's fine without because this is no static call at all. There normally is no reason to use late static binding anyway in PHP, it's just a feature to confuse some users.

Comment: @hakra `parent::` is actually very useful when dealing with classes that inherit from others.

Comment: I learnt from Kevin Yank that we need to use ``static::attribute`` to access property of class which is inheriting and ``$this`` wouldn't work.

Comment: @Mahn: `parent::` is not static and has nothing to do with late static binding.

Comment: @YousufIqbal Kevin Yank is wrong (whoever that is)

Comment: @hakra true, it's just that php docs do call it part of the late static binding implementation of php, see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: @Mahn: True, it does not have *nothing* to do, right. I stand corrected. Also I did misread your comment, for inheritance it is naturally of use. But it still looks unrelated to me.

Comment: `static` is a class scope, like `self` and `parent`; `$this` is an object scope, totally different use.  The class scope are for calling `static` methods, different type of `static` to the scope, PHP really confused things by using the same identifier.

Comment: @Orbling: Hmm, I normally use `parent` to call non-static methods, for example the parent's constructor. Has not much to do with static per-se.

Comment: @hakra: Again a confusion in the PHP syntax.  `parent` is used with the class scope operator (`::`), but is used for object or class method access, which is somewhat confusing and breaks the meaning, but that's PHP legacy for you. LOL

Comment: @Orbling: Well, `::` is just the *Scope Resolution Operator*, so I do not think it breaks the meaning. However, it can look irritating if users assume it is for static access only.

Comment: @hakra: Aye, it is always presented in class context, rather than in mixed context, the arrow `->` operator being used as the deference for object identifiers, using the scope resolution operator in the object context as well in the form of `parent` (which is also used exactly the same for class scope parents) confuses the hell out of a lot of people coming to PHP.  Alright for people like me that remember PHP before OO even, but it's a bit nasty.

Comment: @Orbling: Yes, I also stopped wondering why this was "solved" that way. I sometimes have the feeling that these are all some kind of exploits of the limited parser. `parent->...` does indeed not work, but still it is a reserved word. And then it's named `$this`, so why wasn't there any `$parent`?  Or just `this` in the first place? ^^

Comment: @hakra: Down to the Perl ancestry I suspect, as that uses `$this` and a similar scope system.  `$parent->` would probably make a lot more sense as you say.  Using the `$` is sensible as it's a variable in object context, rather than the class scope, which has no variable about it.  Oh well, the joy of evolutionary OO in PHP, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class B defines a public function called `tellAttribute()` that looks like this:

```
public function tellAttribute(){
    echo $this->attribute;
}
```

You then instantiate class A - a child of class B - and do this:

```
$test = new A();
$test->tellAttribute();
```

So, you instantiate an object of class `A` and then call `tellAttribute()` on this object.  Because the `tellAttribute()` method uses the `$this` variable you are referring to the actual object you have instantiated.  Even though you defined `tellAttribute()` in class `B` - the parent - it will actually be pointing to the child object (an instance of class `A`) in which you have the public `$attribute` property.  That's why it prints `foo` and why you don't need to use `static::`.

On the other hand, consider this:

```
class B {
    public static $attribute = 'foo';
    public function tellAttribute(){
        echo self::$attribute; // prints 'foo'
    }
    public function tellStaticAttribute() {
        echo static::$attribute; // prints 'bar'
    }
}

class A extends B {
    public static $attribute = 'bar';
}

$test = new A();
$test->tellAttribute();
print "<BR>";
$test->tellStaticAttribute();
```

In this example, I'm not using the `$this` variable and am instead using `self::` and `static::`.  The `tellAttribute()` has `self::` and will always print `foo`.  This is because `self::` can only refer to the current class.  The `tellStaticAttribute()` uses `static::` and will print the class 'dynamically'.  I'm not too great on the technical terms etc. so I'll leave you with a link to the manual (which I gather you have already read from your post): http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we need to use the static::$attribute instead of $this->attribute
>   in the following condition : < code >

**No**, you most definitively don't use the `static` keyword in the scenario you describe, and there's no reason for it *not* to work. Think of the context of `$this` as the result of "adding up" all the different inherited classes into one. That is to say, if `class B extends A`, and `class C extends B`, by instantiating C all the properties and functions of the classes A, B and C are available through the `$this` context within the class, and it's perfectly fine for C to use within a function of its own a property defined in B and viceversa, because everything is there as if it were one standalone class in your instance.

Comment: ...unless something further up was defined as `private`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would work .... `$attribute` is public ..... and A has also inherited `tellAttribute()` am not sure what you where expecting.

Comment: To me if we in **class B** use ``$this->attribute`` it would give an error of undefined property because of **earlier static bindings** in php.

Comment: Class B is not extending anything only `class A extends B` definitely there would be an error

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the "static" keyword anywhere.  Your general class setup here is a little odd to me, but if you want $attribute to be a static variable you need to instead type:

```
 public static $attribute = 'foo';
```

Keep in mind a static variable is basically a global variable, and you can review more here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: That has nothing at all to do with [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), other than the shared keyword.

Comment: A variable basically never is a constant. No! You might mean a global variable.

Comment: Did i ask what you just answered ?

Comment: My point was you're not doing late static binding, because you're in a non-static context in the code you put above.  If you refer to the examples in Pete171's post above, you can see the samples inside.  You're just doing basic inheritance in what you posted, hence there's no reason $this wouldn't work.